# Summing up total for all products and their respective quantities ordered XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath

Currently getting a NaN error within XSLT.
I want to get the total value or revenue for all products and their quantities ordered.

XML:

```
<customers>
<customer>
<customername>John</customername>
</customer>
<invoices>
 <invoice>
  <invoicenumber>01</invoicenumber>
  <products>
   <product>
    <productname>candy bar</productname>
    <productamount>6</productamount
    <productcost>2</productcost>
   </product>
  </products>
 </invoice>
 <invoice>
  <invoicenumber>02</invoicenumber>
  <products>
   <product>
    <productname>choco bar</productname>
    <productamount>3</productamount
    <productcost>1</productcost>
   </product>
  </products>
 </invoice>
</invoices>
<customer>
<customername>Fritz</customername>
</customer>
<invoices>
 <invoice>
  <invoicenumber>01</invoicenumber>
  <products>
   <product>
    <productname>Soda</productname>
    <productamount>3</productamount
    <productcost>2</productcost>
   </product>
  </products>
 </invoice>
 <invoice>
  <invoicenumber>02</invoicenumber>
  <products>
   <product>
    <productname>lollipop</productname>
    <productamount>5</productamount
    <productcost>1</productcost>
   </product>
  </products>
 </invoice>
</invoices>
```

And I have tried to adapt a Recursive template.

XSL:

```
Total:  
<xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
<xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="customers/customer/invoices/invoice/products"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="././././././productamount"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="././././././productcost"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="sumProducts">
<xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
<xsl:param name="pName1"/>
<xsl:param name="pName2"/>
<xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
<xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
<xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() > 1]"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="$pName1"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="$pName2"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName1] 
* pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName2]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Desired outcome would be Total = 26

Comment: The only way out of this situation is then you need to read about and learn XSLT -- the problem you have is that even though you are given correct solutions, you don't understand them and cannot use them.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm trying to learn Sir. These are universal templates in which everyone uses, more than likely developed by yourself. I'm currently learning, and that's why I'm here. I asked for pointers not answers....

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few problems with your XSLT. Firstly the setting of the **pNodes** parameter is incorrect

```
<xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="customers/customer/invoices/invoice/products"/>
```

From looking at your XML, it needs to be as follows

```
<xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="customers/invoices/invoice/products/product"/>
```

i.e. The **invoices** element is not within the **customer** element in your sample, and additionally you want to be summing the individual **product** elements.

Next, as Ian Roberts has mentioned, **pName1** and **pName2** look like they should be set to be element names. Currently you are just setting them to the value of whatever of the first occurrence of those elements.

```
<xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="'productamount'"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="'productcost'"/>
```

Finally, the setting of the **pAccum** parameter is wrong. You are currently doing this...

```
<xsl:with-param name="pAccum" 
   select="$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName1] * pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName2]"/>
```

But you have missed out a $ before the second **pNodes** variable. It should be this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="pAccum" 
   select="$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName1] * $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName2]"/>
```

Here's the full XSLT, which should give you 26

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
         <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="customers/invoices/invoice/products/product"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="'productamount'"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="'productcost'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="sumProducts">
      <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
      <xsl:param name="pName1"/>
      <xsl:param name="pName2"/>
      <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="not($pNodes)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
               <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position() &gt; 1]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="$pName1"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="$pName2"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum + $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName1]  * $pNodes[1]/*[name()=$pName2]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: second checking the code, the client element is wrapped around the invoices and products elements, and whilst the pAccum is missing a $ here, my code it isn't --> Typo.

Comment: Still not totalling the product price and their....amount. Is this more than likely to be an XPaTH issue...?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive template looks OK, I think the problem is with your initial `pName1` and `pName2` parameter values.  Try

```
<xsl:with-param name="pName1" select="'productamount'"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pName2" select="'productcost'"/>
```

Your template expects those parameters to be strings containing the *names* of the relevant elements, which is why you need the single quotes inside the double quoted `select` attributes.

Comment: hmm...tried it,still getting NaN. Many recursive templates going around for a single customer or invoce....but not a complete total :(